# Receive Stream of data from Socket Connection -- Android

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, stream, inputstream

### What i want to achieve:

Step 1 >> Open a socket connection :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IPADDRESS, PORTNUMBER);
```

Step 2 >> Start to send & receive data from the Socket:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
pw.write(dataForSocket + "\n");//Sending Data to socket....

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String translatedMessage = br.readLine();
Log.d(TAG, "Translated Message = "+translatedMessage);//Recieving data from Socket...
```

Step 3 >> Receive data from Socket & keep on updating the UI...

### What did i tried till now:

```
public class AsyncThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

//High priority UI variables goes below....
private PrintStream out;
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;


//Medium priority NON-UI variables goes below.....
public static final String SERVER_IP = "203.197.xx.xxx";
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 4xxx;


//Least priority variables goes below.....
private final String TAG = "AsyncThread";


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        String dataForSocket = "A_LARGE_STRING_OF_DATA_SEPERATED_AND_END_WITH_\n";

        /////////////---------CODE TO READ & WRITE------------\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

//            out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
//            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
//
//
//            out.write(dataForSocket.getBytes());
//            String message = in.readLine();
//            Log.d(TAG, "Message from Socket == "+message);



        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // Send first message - Message is being correctly received
              pw.write(dataForSocket + "\n");
//            pw.write(dataForSocket);
        // Send off the data



        String translatedMessage = br.readLine();
        Log.d(TAG, "Translated Message = "+translatedMessage);//In every case this comes null....


//            pw.flush();
//            pw.close();


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}//doInBackground
}//async task class closes here.....
```

But the BufferedReader is always null. So, i don't know what is wrong.

## Thus as a conclusion:

If somebody could give me the exact steps & guide me to get through this scenario then i will be very grateful to you.

P.S. : Till now i am not even able to connect to the Socket :-(
I tried running on device, running on Emulator, running on Genymotion nothing works.

Also, if somebody could provide me some kind of Online tester then please provide me the same.

Comment: "No Tutorial has successfully worked till now" is not a problem description. You need to provide a specific issue and the code that caused it.

Comment: @EJP : Question Updated,
& the BufferedReader is always null. (This is my issue)

Comment: Not possible with the code you've posted. What is the symptom? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? And please make up your mind between 'Data from `BufferedReader` is always null' and '`BufferedReader` is always null'. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP : I want to connect to a Socket, Send some data to socket & receive Stream of bytes from that Socket is my aim.

Comment: And that doesn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: @EJP : Bro, things worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Finally got the solution as:

```
public class AsyncThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    //High priority UI variables goes below....
    private PrintStream out;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;


    //Medium priority NON-UI variables goes below.....
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "203.xxx.xx.xxx";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 4xxx;


    //Least priority variables goes below.....
    private final String TAG = "AsyncThread";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



    StringBuilder buffer = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        String dataForSocket = "A LARGE STRING TO SERVER";

    /////////////---------CODE TO READ & WRITE------------\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    Log.i("ClientActivity", "Connecting...");
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);


        Log.i("ClientActivity", "Sending command.");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        // where you issue the commands
        out.println(dataForSocket);
        Log.i("ClientActivity", "Sent.");

        final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        buffer = new StringBuilder();

        buffer.append(input.readLine());
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside thread : input.readLine() == " + input.readLine());
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside thread : buffer == "+buffer);

}//TRY closes here....
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}//catch closes here.....

return buffer.toString().trim();
 }//doInBackground CLOSES HERE.....
}//AsyncThread class closes here.....
```

Got the reference from :
[how to read socket input stream in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552040/how-to-read-socket-input-stream-in-android?rq=1)

Now, i just need to use a Service instead of Async, & my issues are solved.